# How to set UITableViewCell identifier in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access, ios-4.2, reuseidentifier

I am getting a crash randomly when I select a cell in a UITableView in a viewcontroller in my project.

I think the problem is caused by the cells I am  trying to reuse.

Here is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        [self reinitializeStrArray];

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [strArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
}



- (void)addStrTableToSubView{
    strTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 110, 280, 285)];
    [strTable setDelegate:self];
    [strTable setDataSource:self];

    [self.view addSubview:strTable];

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 83, 280, 28)] autorelease];
    UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(215 / 255.0) green:(145 / 255.0) blue:(0.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
    label.backgroundColor = myColor;

    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = [@"strings" capitalizedString];
    [self.view  addSubview:label];

    [strTable selectRowAtIndexPath:scrollStrIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

I create my table in XCode. So there is no UITableViewCell object in IB which has an identifier.

Is it possible to add this in code while creating the table?
Or is the problem somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: Usually the error gives a hint to where the actual problem occurs. Can you see which line it is?

Comment: i just edited my question to: random crash :]

Comment: The problem is not repeat friendly, sometimes when I build and run I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, when I try to debug it, I cannot reproduce this.. And sometimes the program crashes when I go back and forth between the viewcontrollers of my tabbar and it crashes when i select a cell, but this is also not very stable bug

Comment: From what you say is virtually certain that it is due to an incorrect memory management. More precisely, you're probably doing a release on an autoreleased object. Use the NSZombieEnabled environment variable: you will find the object that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, usually means that there is an incorrect memory management (i.e. an object was improperly released). My suggestion is to enable the NSZombieEnabled environment variable: it will give you more information about what is the object that causes the problem. More info [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).